# URL aliases for non-translated content types revert to /es/node/nid in menu

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have Content Translate enabled and enabled translation on only our Projects content type. I've placed the Language switcher block on a Projects view and Project node page. This is working just fine.

My problem is, if I use the Language switcher on the Projects view for Project page, then click a link in the main menu to a pieces of non-Project content, the path has changed to `/es/node/1` when it should be `/publications`

The link still works, but this is incorrect. The page is in English and now I don't have the nice usability of an attractive path.

Additional information: If I have just used the language switcher to view the Spanish version of a Project, then go directly to `/publications` in the browser search bar, it works and the path stays correct. It has also changed my language selection back to English. I am okay with that, but it's another clue, perhaps.

TLDR I only want `/es/` to appear on pages that are actually in Spanish, and I want my regular paths on non-translated pages to be correct and not switch to `/es/node/1`.